# Как удалить рядом стоящие одинаковые по значению символы, но разные по регистру?

Tags: c++, строки, циклы, for

Пытаюсь создать цикл удаления из строки рядом стоящий повторяющихся по значению символов, но разных по регистру. Т.е при вводе строки  AaBb он должен вывести пустую строку, а при вводе  AaBB он должен вывести BB.
Cмог придумать цикл на проверку подстроки, но он не работает и это неэффективно.

```
string S;
cin >> S;
int k=2;
int lengt= S.size();
for(int i=0; i<S.size(); i++){
label1:
if(lengt>S.size()){
    k=1;
    lengt=S.size();
}
else{
    k=2;
}
if(S.find("Aa")<52){
    S.erase(S.find("Aa"),S.find("Aa")+k);
    goto label1;
}
if(S.find("aA")<52){
    S.erase(S.find("aA"),S.find("aA")+k);
    goto label1;
    }
if(S.find("bB")<52){
    S.erase(S.find("bB"),S.find("bB")+k);
    goto label1;
    }  
if(S.find("Bb")<52){
    S.erase(S.find("Bb"),S.find("Bb")+k);
    goto label1;
}
if(S.find("Cc")<52){
    S.erase(S.find("Cc"),S.find("Cc")+k);
    goto label1;
}
 if(S.find("сС")<52){
    S.erase(S.find("сС"),S.find("сС")+k);
    goto label1;
    } 
}
if(!S.empty()){
    cout<<"Impossible"<<endl;
}
else{
     cout<<"Possible"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Ваш код, не универсальный это раз, второе, зачем вам тут метки? И go-to...

Comment: А как должны обрабатываться последовательности из трёх и более одинаковых символов? Если надо строго две, то используйте `std:: adjacent_find`, если больше - то достаточно `std::unique`.

Comment: Хотя нет, `std::unique` не подойдёт, он в любом случае оставит один из одинаковых символов.

Answer (score 1):

Для этой цели подойдёт функция [std::adjacent_find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find). Она ищет рядом стоящие пары одинаковых элементов массива. Только в данном случае нужно будет дополнительно указать ей, что следует считать равными именно равные по значению символы, но разные по регистру. Для этого надо написать компаратор.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string s = "Have you seen the new Ssang Yong?";
    
    //Напишем функцию компаратора.
    //Компаратор принимает два символа и возвращает истину,
    //если символы равны по значению но разные по регистру.
    auto comparator = [](char left, char right) {
        unsigned char uleft = static_cast<unsigned char>(left);
        unsigned char uright = static_cast<unsigned char>(right);
        bool isEqual = std::tolower(uleft) == std::tolower(uright);
        bool isLeftConverted = uleft == std::tolower(uleft);
        bool isRightConverted = uright == std::tolower(uright);
        return isEqual && (isLeftConverted ^ isRightConverted);
    };
    //Цикл, который ищет одинаковые элементы. В качестве параметра передана функция компаратора.
    for (auto it = std::adjacent_find(s.begin(), s.end(), comparator); 
         it != s.end(); 
         it = std::adjacent_find(it, s.end(), comparator))
    {
        //Удаляем два рядом стоящих символа
        it = s.erase(it, std::next(it, 2));
        
    }
    std::cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/2QPDST

UPD. Если же необходимо обрабатывать не пары, а произвольное количество идущих подряд символов, то последнее вхождение можно найти функцией `std::upper_bound`. Компаратор при этом надо будет переработать.

Comment: [Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper(), tolower(), et al.?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21805674)

Comment: @wololo, в принятом ответе есть пример, который "не решает проблему": `toupper((unsigned)c)`. Здесь подразумевается `unsigned int`? Полагаю так будет правильно: `toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(c))`.

Comment: Да, `unsigned` — это эквивалент `unsigned int`. [dcl.type.simple](http://eel.is/c++draft/tab:dcl.type.simple). «Yes, the argument to `toupper` needs to be converted to `unsigned char` to avoid the risk of undefined behavior.»

Comment: @wololo, спасибо за замечание, исправил.